# PHP 5.4 VS 5.6 BUG

Tags: php

We've found a very interesting bug.

I can not find information about it online.

```
<?php
class Inner
{
    public $text = 'Hello, world';
    function test()
    {
        Outer::wtf();
    }
}
class Outer
{
    public function wtf()
    {
        print $this->text;
    }
}


$i = new Inner;
$i->test();
```

Php 5.4

```
bag.php returns "Hello, world".
```

But, php 5.6

```
bag.php returns error:
"Non-static method Outer::wtf() should not be called statically..."
```

Why?

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Comment: Why is it return "Hello, world"??? Here at least two error

Comment: 1) Calling a static method. 2) Class Outer hasn't $text property

Comment: As the error says, `Outer::wtf()` isn't valid because `wtf()` is not defined as `static`. That it worked at all under 5.4 is quite amazing

Comment: This is the main question. Why does it work on version 5.4 ?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/C8V82, before php 7 its an error, in php 7 its even a fatal error..

Comment: But why is it run on 5.4?? It's imposible, i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with PHP fixing the [incompatible context problem](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.other.incompatible-this)

> Previously deprecated in PHP 5.6, static calls made to a non-static method with an incompatible context will now result in the called method having an undefined $this variable and a deprecation warning being issued.

You can see this when you run your snippet [across different versions](https://3v4l.org/CvZlA)

Prior to 5.6 you get this `E_STRICT`

> Strict Standards: Non-static method Outer::wtf() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /in/CvZlA on line 7

In 5.6 you get

> Deprecated: Non-static method Outer::wtf() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /in/CvZlA on line 7

And finally in 7.0 or later

> Deprecated: Non-static method Outer::wtf() should not be called statically in /in/CvZlA on line 7
>   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /in/CvZlA:14

Comment: I never heard of it! Thanks!